# Webpack + ReactJS performance issue

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, webpack, web-performance

I've created a small ReactJs application which is bundled using Webpack. Backend is done using Java (Spring Boot) and I'm running the app in my laptop (new Macbook Pro). I've tested it in Chrome and noticed that it takes considerably amount of time before REST API call (`find_all`) is invoked from the bundle file (`positions_bundle.js`), see the screenshot below. Does this look like normal performance using these technologies? I've run the front end using both Spring Boot and Webpack dev server and between those there isn't any significant difference.

[image]

EDIT. This is my React class which creates REST API call:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";
import {setPositionData} from "../actions/setPositionData";

class PositionDataFetcher extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }

   componentDidMount(){
      axios.get('http://localhost:9000/jmap/position/find_all')
         .then(function (response) {
            // console.log(response.data);
            this.props.setPositionData(response.data);
         }.bind(this)
         )
         .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
         });
   }
   render(){
      return null;
   }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
   return {
      positionData: state.positionData
   };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
   return bindActionCreators({setPositionData: setPositionData}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(PositionDataFetcher)
```

Comment: It's hard to tell wether there is any optimization required without seeing how you are making the request in your front-end code, but it does seem to take quite a while to even start the request - the request itself is not taking that long to complete once it has started.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. I added the React class where the REST API call is done to my original question.